# How do I scale a background by height in CSS3?

Tags: css

I know that I can use cover or contain value for the 'background-size' property, but is this possible to scale a background by window height?

I've tried

```
background-size: auto contain

background-size: cover contain
```

both didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `contain` and `cover` keywords are meant to be used by themselves; you can't use them for just the width or just the height of a background image, i.e. you can't put two of them together. Furthermore, these two values will *always* scale the image according to its aspect ratio.

If you mean to preserve the image's aspect ratio, while keeping the entire image visible (contained) within its box, just specify `contain` by itself:

```
background-size: contain;
```

If you mean to preserve only the background image's original width, and stretch its height along with its containing box, without preserving the image's aspect ratio, you will have to specify its width in pixels and 100% for its height.

So for a background image that's 200 pixels wide, you'll use:

```
background-size: 200px 100%;
```

Don't forget to give your image an appropriate `background-position` and `background-repeat`.

Comment: BoltClock // Thank you for your post. No..I like to preserve the image's aspect ratio. Here's an example.. http://qacode.com/test/slideshow/slide.html. This is js version..

Comment: oops...how could I miss that...Thank you!!